# Why is node compile.js command is not showing any results?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am developing smart contracts on vs code and have been trying to compile the contract. I believe that after running the command 'node compile.js' I am supposed to see the bytecode and ABI information pop up as a result, however I am not getting anything. Why is my terminal in vs code not showing the expected results and how can get them?

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc4xy.png)

Comment: please provide  code ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.